# Django session variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django

Can i use Django session variable in JavaScript?

In django:

```
request.session['email'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
```

In JS:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("email")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple view:

```
class SessionVarView(TemplateView)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(request.session[kwargs['key']])
```

and in urls.py add:

```
url(r'^session/(?P<key>[^/]+)$', SessionVarView.as_view(), name='session-var'),
```

Then you could get it from JS via http://your.site.address/session/key_name_here or something similar.

(note - this is from the top of my head, and is not tested)

Comment: I do not think you should do this since a session variable can contain information the user should not be able to get, so you should always filter which variables are allowed before returning their value. Please do not forget this!